# Why doesn't `bar` in this code have static storage duration?

Tags: c, static, scope, declaration

Code goes first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
        static int bar;
}

int main()
{
        bar++;
        return 0;
}
```

The compiler(Clang) complains:

```
static.c:10:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'bar'
```

Shouldn't the statement `static int bar;` in `foo()` give `bar` static storage duration, which makes it declared and initialized prior to main function?

Comment: It does, but is not in the scope of `main`.

Comment: What has storage duration to do with scope/visibility?

Comment: Please do not add additional question once the question in the question has been answered. I'm rolling back the addition. Let us know if you disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the *scope* of a variable with the *storage duration*.

As mentioned in the `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers*,

- for *file scope*

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
>   appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which
>   terminates at the end of the translation unit. [...]

and for *function* (or *block*) scope

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. [...]

In your case, `bar` has the file scope in `foo()`. So this is not *visible* in `main()`.

OTOH, for the *storage duration* part,

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

So, to summarize, `bar` has static storage duration, but the scope is limited to the `foo()` function. So, it is

> *declared and initialized prior to `main()` function*

(before `main()` starts, to be exact) but not visible and accessible in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Marking something as `static` within a function relocates its storage off of the stack and allows its value to persist across multiple calls.

Marking something `static`, however, does nothing to change the scope of the variable.  While you certainly could create a pointer that is aimed at `bar` and manipulate it from `main`, the compiler will view `bar` as undefined within `main` because of scoping.